# Notepad++ regex to extract usernames only

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have this list below:

```
originalscrape,scrapeDate,userId,username,full_name,is_private,follower_count,following_count,media_count,biography,hasProfilePic,external_url,email,contact_phone_number,address_street,isbusiness,Engagement %,MostRecentPostDate,AvgLikes,AvgComments,category,businessJoinDate,businessCountry,businessAds,countryCode,cityName,isverified
,04/16/2020 01:52 AM,="23227902981",weare2fabtees,2 FAB Tees,False,0,0,0,,False,,,,,No,0,Has no posts.,0,0,,,,,,,No
,04/16/2020 01:55 AM,="13096194464",_jomakesmusic,J. DouBleUpEnT,False,0,0,0,,False,,,,,No,0,Has no posts.,0,0,,,,,,,No
,04/16/2020 01:59 AM,="3174832099",hiveproperties,Hive Property Management,False,0,0,0,,False,,,,,No,0,Has no posts.,0,0,,,,,,,No
,04/16/2020 02:15 AM,="2177511355",brazilianmalemodel,Brazilian Male Model Magazine,False,0,0,0,,False,,,,,No,0,Has no posts.,0,0,,,,,,,No
,04/16/2020 02:17 AM,="31486554680",1freshcobar_double_up_ent,Fre⚡️hCbArDOUBLEUP,False,0,0,0,,False,,,,,No,0,Has no posts.,0,0,,,,,,,No
,04/16/2020 02:25 AM,="7008181835",gpop.finearts,Fine Art Photography Prints,False,0,0,0,,False,,,,,No,0,Has no posts.,0,0,,,,,,,No
```

I would like to get the Usernames only as below:

```
weare2fabtees
_jomakesmusic
hiveproperties
brazilianmalemodel
1freshcobar_double_up_ent
gpop.finearts
```

I've tried to Search for: `",*$` and replace with nothing but giving me replace: no occurrence was found.

I wish somebody who can help me to find the right Regex to extract the Usernames only.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

**Find What**: `^(?:[^,\r\n]*,){3}([^,\r\n]+).*`
**Replace With**: `$1`

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[^,\r\n]*,){3}` - three occurrences of

  - `[^,\r\n]*` - any 0 or more occurrences of any char but `,`, CR and LF
  - `,` - a comma
- `([^,\r\n]+)` - Group 1: any one or more occurrences of any char but `,`, CR and LF
- `.*` - the rest of the line.

The replacement pattern is `$1`, the Group 1 value.

See the Notepad++ demo and settings:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Find what: `^.*?",(.*?),.*`
Replace with: `$1`